# How to click on button without id at table

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I want to click on the edit button in any row. For example, I would like to click on the sign button the record with TRTL in it.

I tried it like this but I got an error;

> ```
> base.Driver.findElement(By.xpath("//td[.='" + "TRTL" + "']/following-sibling::td//button[@data-original-title='Sign']")).click();
> ```

Below is the HTML source of the "`Sign`" button:

```html
<div class="content content-narrow" css="1">
  <div class="block" id="grdPendingMeetingList" style="">
    <div class="block-header" style="">
      <h3 class="block-title"></h3>
    </div>
    <div class="block-content">
      <table class="js-table-sections table table-hover">
        <thead>
          <tr>
            <th style="">Kararlar</th>
            <th> </th>
          </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody style="">
          <tr>
            <td style="">
              <!-- react-text: 1067 -->TRTL
              <!-- /react-text -->
              <!-- react-text: 1068 -->-
              <!-- /react-text -->
              <!-- react-text: 1069 -->14/02/2018 14:40 Tarihli Müzakereli Yönetim Kurulu Toplantısı Kararları
              <!-- /react-text -->
            </td>
            <td class="text-center">
              <div class="btn-group"><button class="btn btn-sm btn-default" type="button" data-toggle="tooltip" title="" data-original-title="Sign"><!-- react-text: 1073 --> <!-- /react-text --><i class="fa fa-pencil"></i></button><button class="btn btn-sm btn-danger" type="button"
                  data-toggle="tooltip" title="" data-original-title="Delete"><i class="fa fa-trash"></i></button></div>
            </td>
          </tr>
        </tbody>
      </table><button class="btn btn-default push-10-r push-20" id="btnBack" type="button" style=""><i class="si si-arrow-left"></i><!-- react-text: 1079 --> <!-- /react-text --><!-- react-text: 1080 -->Geri<!-- /react-text --></button></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: @Sevel...there are three buttons...which one you are talking about?

Comment: I want to click on the sign button @Gaurav

Comment: Instead of xpath, Try linktext and see @Sevel

Answer (score 0):

To click on the button with text as **Sign** you can use the following line of code :

```
base.Driver.findElement(By.xpath("//td[.,='TRTL']//following::td[1]//button[@class='btn btn-sm btn-default' and contains(.,'Sign')]/i[@class='fa fa-pencil']")).click();
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
base.Driver.findElement(By.xpath("//[@id="grdPendingMeetingList"]/div[2]/table/tbody/tr/td[2]/div/button[1]")).click();
```

Tip : please make the **Sign** and **Delete** of size **Geri**. They look very very tiny and are almost invisible.

Answer (score 0):

In this situations I usually use get all the 'td' and put inside a List . Then I make a loop through looking for a certain element, in your case, the "Sign". When I find the desired element, I give the command click. An example is given below.

```
List<WebElement> columns = dateWidget.findElements(By.tagName("td"));
    for (WebElement cell : columns) {
        if (cell.getText().equals("Sign")) {
            cell.findElement(By.linkText(Sign)).click();
            break;
        }
    }
```